# Windows Forms Application C# - Tab Control items shift location after running on debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Currently working on a Form in Visual Studio. My form has a tab control with 4 tabs and one particular tab experiences some issues after running on debug mode. Once I stop and go back to build mode, all items (buttons, labels, textboxes) shift downwards and I am left with a huge blank space the size of the tab height. This means I have to scroll down the tab to find my buttons. This happens after every debug and the "blank spaces" add up on top of another, pushing all the buttons further down.

The tab is set to `AutoScroll: True` and `Dock: Fill`. I set items to `Locked: True` but issue still occurs.

Any idea as to why this is occurring?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `Location` property for the tab control. You can do this from properties window or explicitly assign `System.Drawing.Point` object to this property. Similarly for `Size` property you can use `System.Drawing.Size`

e.g:

```
TabControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);

TabControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(450, 295);
```

I know usually this is already taken care of by Visual Studio, still I prefer setting locations and sizes manually so that I can be sure it's working in the way I want it to work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found instead that modifying all of the buttons to `Anchor` to `Top, Left` and keeping `Locked` as `True` helped. Will resort to your suggestion if issue resurfaces.